# Making Directive function callable from Window scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth

At the last step of the Oauth jig, I'd like the popup window to call a function from its parent, `window.opener`, before closing.  For example, after the user has entered his valid credentials, the popup window is redirected to a page containing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.opener.postAuthCallback();
  window.close();
</script>
```

The trouble is, I'm using AngularJS and the function I want to call (which displays a progress bar, etc) is part of a directive.  Does anyone know of a way to let `postAuthCallback` be associated with the directive's scope?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use events.

When you open the new window, add an event handler to it:

```
var win = window.open("/");
win.onload = function () {
    win.onbeforeunload = function () {
        //call your postAuthCallback function  
    }
}
```

Then you can just call the function from inside your angularjs environment.